# Google map API V3 issue closing the infoWindow when opened from a link

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am migrating from V2 to V3 on google map with multiple markers and info windows and have the map working fine, when a marker is clicked the infowindow opens and close fine.

Beside the map I am doing a list of all points (markers) in a regular text link format, when a user click "cinema" for instance the corresponding infowindow opens up. I have this working but with problems. Firstly, the map itself does not move to open the infowindows which can then be half hidden and when clicking to close the infowindows, it it doesn't.
On version 2 I used Loughcrew to do this.
Here is script I have at the moment:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:solid 1px black; "></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var myLatlng = new Array();
   var  marker = new Array();
   var infowindow = new Array();                            

   function initialize() {
      //set the map options
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.50046357326504,-6.8280029296875),
          streetViewControl: true,
          overviewMapControl:true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
      myLatlng[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(53.738315087044704,-7.80029296875);
      //marker
      marker[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatlng[0],
         map: map,
         icon: 'bus.png',
         title:"This is test 1"
      });
      infowindow[0] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: 'Hey, here is come info'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener( marker[0], 'click', function() {
         infowindow[0].open(map, marker[0]);
      });

      myLatlng[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(53.12633883947352,-7.3443603515625);
      //marker
      marker[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatlng[1],
         map: map,
         icon: 'tennis-sports.png',
         title:"This is another test again"
      });

      infowindow[1] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: 'And more info here!'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener( marker[1], 'click', function() {
         infowindow[1].open(map, marker[1]);
      });

/********************* end of markers  ********************/
   }//end initialize

   function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxx&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
      document.body.appendChild(script);
   }

   window.onload = loadScript;

</script>

<a href="javascript:infowindow[1].open(map, marker[1]);" id="link1">Test link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
<a href="javascript:openInfoWindow(1);" id="link1">Test link</a>

function openInfoWindow(i) {
    infowindow[i].open(map, marker[i])
    map.setCenter(marker[i].getPosition())
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your suggestion and the problem still is the same.

Comment: So what is happening? Firebug tells you something? Can you post URL?

Comment: Define `var map` outside init() as a global variable. function openInfoWindow() 'can't see' variables defined in othr function.

Comment: Thank you Odoakr, this was the problem. Thanks to user1620090 as well